# Upgrading custom membership providers from mvc4 to mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5

I have upgraded a web project from mvc4 to mvc5. The provider used below is null after the upgrade. Should I register my provider in a different way in mvc5 compared to mvc4?

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider"  userIsOnlineTimeWindow="10">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="MyMembershipProvider, MyWebAssembly" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" applicationName="MyAppName" type="MyRoleProvider, MyWebAssembly" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: @Paddy No, I havn´t solve this...

Comment: Nuget package included two web matrix dlls in my project. They were causing this issue for me and removing them seemed to solve it without further issue.